# Google Apps Script with ContentService Issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I grabbed some links with Google Spreadsheets' importXML() from a Webpage and would like to put it to a webpage, following the docs here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content

My script is:

```
function doGet() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Nhud6O4odcsqgav5A9GrlYfXe9xSLUmOgeft5VBAGxA");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Result");
 var link = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, 1, 1);
 var title = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, 1, 1);
 var script = 'function makeLink() {var link = document.getElementById("sidebar"); link.setAttribute("href","' + 
    link + '"); link.innerHTML = "' + title + '";}';
 Logger.log(script); 
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(script).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Here is the webpage where I want to put the links: http://gimoya.bplaced.net/gapps.html

The html code is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxMTnkqCllf446UBF6j3OV4Gn2m1g_VXRvvaggHTc4DkiWcyOo/exec">
       </script>
    </head>
    <a id="sidebar" onload = "makeLink()" target="_blank"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the makeLink() function isn't called, or at least it is without effect, when the page is loaded. In the Web Console I can see that the function makeLink() is loaded properly and I also can call in manually from there and it is working..

If someone has a clue, please help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a Caja related issue, try loading after when *document.ready* with Jquery.

Comment: No chance to get around this without Jquery?